# proof by letters with characters

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

An authentication system accepts passwords that are composed of lowercase letters from a to z and digits from 0 to 9. Prove that, in this system, given any set of 3000 passwords, there must be at least three passwords that begin with the same pair of characters (in the same order), for example, st4fk7 and std3gy37.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please [edit] your question to explain what you know, show what you have attempted, and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bin for every possible beginning of a password, from "aa", "ab" all the way to "99". Then throw each of the present passwords into its bin.